# Чтение файла по частям

Tags: c#

Есть вот такой метод, который читает по частям файл.

```
 public static byte[] Read_Blok(string path)
 {
     int size = 1024 * 1024;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; // размер буффера
     int count = 0; // число реально прочитанных байт

     using (var fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
     {
         count = fstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         return buffer;
     }
 }
```

В этом коде я все время буду читать только начало файла, вопрос,а как мне организовать смещение чтобы в цикле мне каждый раз читать новую часть файла, а не одну и тоже.

Comment: 1. `Seek`. 2. Ты теряешь информацию о том, сколько прочитано. Да и вообще чтение неверное. 3. Лучше не переоткрывать постоянно файл.

Comment: Откройте стрим вне этого метода один раз. В этот метод передавайте уже открытый поток.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov получается это так,вот сам метод 
отредактировал в вопросе

Comment: Примерно так. Теперь верните вопрос на место, а этот код оформите ответом. Только нужно еще возвращать из метода количество реально прочитанных байт.